# Copy files with the same names to their own places in one command

Tags: linux

I need to copy files with the same name in multiple directories to their same places,

For Example, Files are as follows:

```
/var/Aug/test 

/var/Sep/test 

/var/Oct/test
```

And I need to copy them to their own places but named test_1

> ```
> /var/Aug/test_1 
>
> /var/Sep/test_1 
>
> /var/Oct/test_1
> ```

if I run ls command

```
ls /var/Aug
```

Output should be:

```
test test_1
```

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
 find . -name 'test'|xargs -I{} cp {} "{}_1"
```

Comment: I did it with a simple loop script